# Magento set product list order by attribute values

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, sorting

I am trying to provide the custom attribute in sort-by, when am trying to fetching the products list order by custom attribute those are not in Ascending order.

```
  if ($attribute == 'paidship') {
        //$dir = 'ASC';
        if (isset($this->_joinFields[$attribute])) {

            $this->getSelect()->order($this->_getAttributeFieldName($attribute) . ' ' . $dir,'e.name'.$dir);

        }
    }
```

My custom attribute is "paidship", i want fetch them in first in Ascending order and remaining products should display after those products and those are also be in Ascending order

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom attribute to sort the collection as follows:

```
$collection->addAttributeToSort('paidship','ASC');
```

Comment: Sorry, i am writing script for addAttributeToSort        if (isset($this->_joinFields[$attribute])) {     $this->getSelect()->order($this->_getAttributeFieldName($attribute) . ' ' . $dir);  return $this;            }
            return $this;
        } elseif($attribute == 'is_saleable'){
            $this->getSelect()->order("is_saleable " . $dir);
            return $this;
        }